# I want to create a fast switch for AC current (RF output) in GHz range using MOSFETs

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I am currently creating a modulator for AC switching applications. The input is an AC current source oscillating at a peak of 3 GHz. I want this AC current to be switched on and off basically with a minimum on time of 5 us. I have a pulse blaster which can supply pulses of up to 3.6 V DC. I want the MOSFET to be on 5 us and in this 5 us it should conduct an RF signal or AC signal with frequency 3 GHz.

Any recommendations for what circuit I could use to achieve this task?

If any additional information is required I'm happy to provide.

Comment: It seems like you are saying you want to ground the current source output with a MOSFET. Is that true?

Comment: You give peak but what's the valley (minimum frequency)? You say "AC current", what current? We also need to know voltage and impedance, and permissible mismatch/SWR, required flatness, insertion loss (when on), isolation (when off), etc.

Comment: I will be honest I do not have much idea of what those terms mean. I specialize in optics and I just need this to modulate an RF signal. The source generator is a pico source AS108 and the TTL generator is a spincore pb12-100-4k PCIE minimum frequency is around 900 MHz. AC current is basically the RF signal from the picosource synthesiser. insertion loss as low as possible but I will have an amplifier so i can amplify the signal again its not a big deal. isolation should be good not alot of leakage when off. since RF signal is in the realm of mV. I do not know about SWR and required flatness

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is an RF analogue switch that can be driven by your on/off signal source. The pass-through bandwidth of the switch will need to be over the 3GHz signal source you're trying to switch. Do a search for an analogue RF SPST or SPDT switch and I'm sure you will find what you're looking for.

Comment: searching the term pass through frequency doesnt give me anything. Ive even searched for specific MOSFETS passthrough frequency but they dont give me anything. and there are many types of SPST switches online how do I know which one will work for RF signals as it isnt written if they will accept RF or not. (Ive searched for RF SPST swicthes and RF analogue SPST switches)

Comment: The search is ment to be for RF "analogue switch", then check the pass-through bandwidth parameter. Or better still contact MiniCircuits and try to get such a switch module off-the-shelf since you are having trouble with the sourcing. I'm sure they may be able to propose something suitable or may be able to guide you in the right direction. Just tell them the issues you're having etc ...